# VBA - Excel Add-In menu disappears when graph is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I've created an Add-In menu for my spreadsheet in VBA (code below).
I can access this menu fine, but it disappears when I select a graph (pictures below).

Is there a way to access this menu whilst I've selected a graph?

Cell selected, add-in menu 'Graph' accessible:

[image: Cell selected, add-in menu 'Graph' accessible]

Graph selected, add-in menu 'Graph' has disappeared:

[image]

VBA code:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim cmbBar As CommandBar
Dim cmbControl As CommandBarControl
On Error Resume Next
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("Graph").Delete
Set cmbBar = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar")
Set cmbControl = cmbBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, temporary:=True) 'adds a menu item to the Menu Bar
With cmbControl
    .Caption = "&Graph" 'names the menu item
    With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton) 'adds a dropdown button to the menu item
        .Caption = "&Graph layout" 'adds a description to the menu item
        .OnAction = "FormatCharts" 'runs the specified macro
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should really be using the CustomUI for this, rather than the old commandbars code. I suspect the issue is that the Worksheet Menu bar deactivates when you select a chart. If you really want to persist with CommandBars, try creating a new commandbar, then add your control to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself in the end, with some help from Rory's comment above which pointed me in the right direction:

Using a 'chart menu bar' instead of a 'worksheet menu bar' fixes the issue

```
Set cmbBar = Application.CommandBars("Chart Menu Bar")
```

Edit: Weirdly, as soon as more than one graph is selected, the chart menu disappears and the worksheet menu reappears, worked around it by adding the menu to both the worksheet menu bar and the chart menu bar but -.-